# Check for a part of string within an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

I want to check if a part of a string (not the full-string, as it will be variable) is present in an array.

```
$test = array(
  0 => 'my searcg',
  1 => 'set-cookie: shdugdd',
  2 => 'viable: dunno'
);
```

What i want is check if either of the keys has the string "set-cookie" and if so, return the key. I can't check for full string as the `set-cookie` value will differ every time. It might not be present as well, so need to check that as well.

I know i can loop through the array and check the same and get the results, but am looking for a more concise/efficient answer. Having trouble getting a solution.

Comment: The loop solution would be at most 3 lines - the `for` statement, the `strpos` check and a closing bracket. How more concise could it be? :)

Comment: what issues do you have with `loop through the array and check the same and get the results` ?

Comment: My Recommendation use array_walk function of php

Comment: @Laurent Yeah, that won't be but was curious if it could be solved in a more generic way. Like an extended version of `in_array`, with strpos'ing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foreach($test as $key=> $value)
{
  if (strpos($value,'set-cookie') !== false) 
 {
  echo $key; // print key containing searched string
  }
}
```

Here is another alternative. ([working example](http://codepad.org/57nJNGLl))

```
   $matches = preg_grep('/set-cookie/', $test); 
    $keys    = array_keys($matches); 

    print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I know this can be done as pointed in my post, but anyway thanks :)

Comment: @Pushpesh I have edited my answer with another alternative. Please check.

Comment: @Pushpesh I have added demo link to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there you can use array_walk function of php

Here is the detailed explanation.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function returnkey($arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        if(strpos($val, 'set-cookie') !== false) {
            return $key;
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function to match $str in an array.

Use case: `$key = strInArray ( 'set-cookie', $array );`

```
function strInArray ( $str, $array ) {

    if ( array_walk ( $array, function ( $val, $key ) use ( &$data, $str ) {
        if ( strpos ( $val, $str ) !== false ) {
            $data = $key;
        }
    }));

    return $data;
}
```